# What is the difference between “serious” and “self-serious”

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

I encountered this descriptor in an essay about "bitcoin carnivores":

> The idea is simple: Use only Bitcoin, eat only meat. The espoused benefits are as much spiritual as they are financial and physical, and its advocates are **self-serious**. <sup>[source](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/ne74nw/inside-the-world-of-the-bitcoin-carnivores)</sup>

None of the dictionaries I ordinarily consult have a definition for *self-serious*, though [Wordnik has some examples](https://www.wordnik.com/words/self-serious):

> the show is ostensibly set in Portland, OR, but acts more broadly as a parody/homage to the "**self-serious** liberal" culture that can be found in many towns.

> Presented without commentary, the most absurd, comical, **self-serious** and/or humorless moments from the pilot episode of "Smash."

> After all, if ribbing of the sort Huddleston gets from @PrezHuddleston whose true identity remains a mystery to its muse stakes its humor on the notion that college presidents are stodgy and **self-serious**, then attempting to silence those satirists outright might reinforce the stereotype.

It seems like it has something to do with how seriously something takes itself, but I'm uncertain how **self-seriousness** is different from regular **seriousness**. Can something be self-serious but not serious, or serious but not self-serious?

Is self-seriousness actually a descriptor for a distinct kind of seriousness, or is it more a way for the writer to demonstrate a negative opinion about the seriousness? That is, by describing something as "self-serious" does a writer mean to say the subject takes itself seriously but the writer does not?

Is there a formal definition of self-serious in any particular field of study or inquiry, or is its use entirely informal?

Answer (score 3):

In the contexts you provided, self-serious seems to mean "take themselves too seriously." In other words, they are pretentious, and lacking in self-awareness.

The most pertinent definition of serious [according to Merriam-Webster is](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serious?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)

```
not joking or trifling
```

So while both serious and self-serious imply sincere belief, self-serious also includes a lack of self-awareness and a degree of seriousness that is worthy of mockery.

A programmer who believes he's doing important work is serious about his job. A programmer who believes he's doing the most important work in the history of the world is self-serious.

Comment: So, would you agree that "self-serious" is not a strictly neutral descriptor, but one that carries the judgment that the thing being described is not worthy of being serious about?

Comment: I did when I wrote this answer, but looking again at your last example (stodgy and self-serious college professors) I'm forced to reconsider. Actually, I think it is the manner of the seriousness that is mockable rather than the object of the seriousness. A programmer who thinks he's doing the most important job in the world could be described as self-serious; though his actual work is not necessarily mockable, his attitude towards it is.